# netstat lists ip addresses not found in "ip address list" or ifconfig--what's going on?

Tags: networking, network-interface

My understanding was that`sudo netstat -tlupn` gives me all the addresses/ports that have processes listening and that `ip address list` or `ifconfig` (though I guess the latter is deprecated) would give all the network interfaces with their associated ip addresses.  So what's up with

```
ip address list | grep  127.0.0.53
```

returning nothing when

```
sudo netstat -tlupn | grep 127.0.0.53
```

returns

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      714/systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           714/systemd-resolve
```

Similar thing with `sudo netstat -tlupn | grep 224.0.0.251`:

```
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           29533/chrome
...
```

What am I not understanding? (Running Ubuntu 18.04 inside VirtualBox fwiw).

Answer (score 2):

`ip address list` gives you IP addresses of your interfaces. And list of interfaces. Among this addresses, you could find this this subnet: `inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo`. This is [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback). `/8` means that for you accessible this ip's range: `127.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255`.

Comment: So basically that whole address range is assigned to the `lo` interface?  But this doesn't seem to work for my other interfaces.  Is there something in the `ip address list` output that tells you an interface works/doesn't this way, or is it just that it is a loopback interface?

Comment: The loopback interface is special, for historical reasons.  " (g)  { 127, <any> }  Internal host loopback address.  Addresses of this form MUST NOT appear outside a host."  From https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to metallic's answer that for the loopback interface you need to consider the address *range*, the IPv4 address range 224.0.0.0-239.255.255.255 is reserved for multicast traffic.  To view multicast addresses in use by your system, you would use

```
ip maddress show
```

rather than

```
ip address list
```

which will list the *unicast* addresses.